# How to update key value as per condition using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some array of objects value and I need to check some key value pair and update the objects accordingly using Javascript. I am explaining my code below.\

```
let arr =[
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name':'Raj',
    "code":0
  },
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name':'Raj',
    'code': 1
  },
  {
    'id':32,
    'name':'Krishna',
    'code':1
  },
  {
    'id':32,
    'name':'fff',
    'code':0
  },
  {
    'id':43,
    'name':'FAQ',
    'code':0
  }
]

let arr1 = arr.map((item,i) => {
  const found = arr.some(el => el.code === 1);
  if(found) {
    
  }
})
```

Here I have array of objects and I need if any record has `code=1` as per `id` then all record's `code=1` belongs to same `id`. My expected output will be like below.

```
let arr =[
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name':'Raj',
    "code":1
  },
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name':'Raj',
    'code': 1
  },
  {
    'id':32,
    'name':'Krishna',
    'code':1
  },
  {
    'id':32,
    'name':'fff',
    'code':1
  },
  {
    'id':43,
    'name':'FAQ',
    'code':0
  }
]
```

Here for id=11 there is one record which has code=1 so all records belongs to id=11 the code value will be 1;

Comment: I am not getting what is your question here?

Comment: First it will check for same id is there any code==1 if present it will update code=1 for that id.

Comment: There is difference in code key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have accepted it as an answer. Your question is wrongly framed. My solution just check if the id has some `code` value apart from `0` then it would be applicable to all of the objects of that `id`.

```js
var arr =[ { 'id': 11, 'name':'Raj', "code":0 }, { 'id': 11, 'name':'Raj', 'code': 1 }, { 'id':32, 'name':'Krishna', 'code':1 }, { 'id':32, 'name':'fff', 'code':0 }, { 'id':43, 'name':'FAQ', 'code':0 }];

var result = arr.map((k,i,self)=>({...k, code:self.find(p=>p.id==k.id && p.code != 0)?.code || k.code}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to first filter on the list again to find if there are any items with the same id that have code === 1.

That can be done in multiple ways. Below is one example

```js
let arr = [{
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'Raj',
    "code": 0
  },
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'Raj',
    'code': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 32,
    'name': 'Krishna',
    'code': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 32,
    'name': 'fff',
    'code': 0
  },
  {
    'id': 43,
    'name': 'FAQ',
    'code': 0
  }
]

let arr1 = arr.map((item, i) => {
  const currentId = item.id;
  const itemsWithSameId = arr.filter(el => el.id === currentId);
  const found = itemsWithSameId.some(el => el.code === 1);
  if (found) {
    return { ...item, code: 1};
  }
  return item;
})

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 11,
  name: 'Raj',
  code: 0
}, {
  id: 11,
  name: 'Raj',
  code: 1
}, {
  id: 32,
  name: 'Krishna',
  code: 1
}, {
  id: 32,
  name: 'fff',
  code: 0
}, {
  id: 43,
  name: 'FAQ',
  code: 0
}]

const update = (id, code) => {
  const updatedArr = arr.map(el => {
    if (el.id === id) el.code = code
    return el
  })
  return updatedArr
}

const result = update(11, 1)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'Raj',
    "code": 0
  },
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name': 'Raj',
    'code': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 32,
    'name': 'Krishna',
    'code': 1
  },
  {
    'id': 32,
    'name': 'fff',
    'code': 0
  },
  {
    'id': 43,
    'name': 'FAQ',
    'code': 0
  }
]

const foundItems = arr.filter(el => el.code === 1);

arr.forEach(el => {
  if (foundItems.find(e => e.id === el.id)) {
    el.code = 1;
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr =[
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name':'Raj',
    "code":0
  },
  {
    'id': 11,
    'name':'Raj',
    'code': 1
  },
  {
    'id':32,
    'name':'Krishna',
    'code':1
  },
  {
    'id':32,
    'name':'fff',
    'code':0
  },
  {
    'id':43,
    'name':'FAQ',
    'code':0
  }
]

   arr.forEach(el => {  if(el.code === 1){
   arr.map((obj)=>{
if(obj.id==el.id){
   obj.code=1
}
    })
  }})
 




console.log(arr)
```

solved

Answer (score 0):

I would group the item based upon their id. Then filter out all groups of which at least one item has code 1. Then set the code of all items in those groups to 1.

```js
function groupBy(iterable, fn) {
  const groups = new Map();
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const key = fn(item);
    if (!groups.has(key)) groups.set(key, []);
    groups.get(key).push(item);
  }
  return groups;
}

let arr =[
  { id: 11, name: 'Raj',     code: 0 },
  { id: 11, name: 'Raj',     code: 1 },
  { id: 32, name: 'Krishna', code: 1 },
  { id: 32, name: 'fff',     code: 0 },
  { id: 43, name: 'FAQ',     code: 0 }
];

Array.from(groupBy(arr, item => item.id).values())
     .filter(group => group.some(item => item.code == 1))
     .flat(1)
     .forEach(item => item.code = 1);

console.log(arr);
```